# PostMan Unauthorized 401

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-passport, unauthorized

I'm having an issue when trying to register a new user in my Laravel application that uses Passport for API authentication. Here's the scenario and the error I'm facing:

Scenario:
I'm developing a RESTful API with Laravel and using Passport for user authentication. I'm trying to create an endpoint to register new users through a POST request to /api/register.

Error:
When I attempt to register a new user by sending the appropriate JSON data via Postman, I receive the following error:

json
Copy code
{
"name":"paco",
"email": "paco@example.net",
"password": "password123"
}
{
"error": "Unauthorized2"
}
Relevant Code:
I've configured my PassportAuthMiddleware middleware to protect the API routes, but I'm puzzled as to why I'm receiving this error even on the registration route that shouldn't be protected.

Questions:

What could be causing this "Unauthorized2" error when trying to register a new user?
What steps should I take to resolve this issue and allow registration requests to pass without errors?

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsxNS.png)
[Middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thSCz.png)

Im trying to use withoutMiddleware, but still doesnt work
[api.php (Routes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j1TI.png)

AuthController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use App\Enums\Roles;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Registro de un nuevo usuario.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 400);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            'role' => Roles::USER, // Asignamos el rol de usuario por defecto al registrar
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 201);
    }

    /**
     * Login de usuario existente.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = $request->user();
            $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

            // Verificar el rol del usuario y redirigir según el rol
            if ($user->role === Roles::ADMIN) {
                return response()->json(['token' => $token, 'role' => Roles::ADMIN], 200);
            } elseif ($user->role === Roles::USER) {
                return response()->json(['token' => $token, 'role' => Roles::USER], 200);
            }

            // En caso de que el rol no esté definido o no coincida con los roles permitidos
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
}
```

I can't even access the register or login routes, which shouldn't be protected by any middleware.

I have even opened a GitHub repository so that the error can be seen if necessary. I have been trying to solve it for several days and I am not able to. I have discussed the problem with my teacher, and we haven't been able to solve it together... I don't know what else to do; it's my final project for the boot camp :') I would love to be able to solve it and move on to testing.
https://github.com/LemonRH/TestSprint5

I have tried many different things, but none of them work. I have tried to do some var dumps, but it doesn't even get to that point. I'm starting to think it must be a stupid error that I'm not able to see. I have tried to review most of my project-related files with ChatGPT, and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Checked your GitHub repository and found some passport configuration issues in your code, then I update your code in 3 files like below snippets:

First Change in `api.php`

```
    use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
    use App\Http\Middleware\PassportAuthMiddleware;
    
    // Rutas de autenticación
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->withoutMiddleware(PassportAuthMiddleware::class);
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->withoutMiddleware(PassportAuthMiddleware::class);
```

Second Change in `App\Http\Controllers\AuthController's` `register` function :

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 400);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            'role' => Roles::USER, // Asignamos el rol de usuario por defecto al registrar
        ]);
        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
        }

        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 201);
    }
```

And last `App\Models\User` :

Remove

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens; // Importa el trait HasApiTokens
```

and Add

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

This is the trait for Laravel passport which create access token.

After these changes, your registration and generation accessToken completely working fine.

Note: if you will face `Personal access client not found` error while creating accessToken run this command to fix `php artisan passport:install`

For more details you can check document : https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport

Thank you!

Comment: Hello!, it worked

https://ibb.co/nwDYprv

Now i can create users, but i got some NULLS, i have to fix that.

Also Postman is giving me this error ErrorException: Attempt to read property &quot;secret&quot; on null in file C:\xampp\htdocs\DiceGame\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php on line 97

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\DiceGame\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(270): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions-&gt;handleError(2, 'Attempt to read...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 97)

Answer (score 0):

Change `use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;` to `use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;` in User.php

then comment this `\App\Http\Middleware\PassportAuthMiddleware::class` in app\Http\Kernel.php

Comment: Hello sir,

I tried to comment that line before, but i think u are right about this:

 use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

The problem is that when i comment this line

            //\App\Http\Middleware\PassportAuthMiddleware::class, // Agrega la línea para el middleware de Passport

My PostMan gives me this error

500error
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [AuthController] does not exist. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Sprint5\DiceGame\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 891
 
screenshot
https://ibb.co/2h6kz2P